# DisplayPorts in ThinkPad USB-C dock are not detected

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad

My computer is a ThinkPad T480s and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 running lightdm on Unity. I can use my mouse and keyboard when it is plugged in to the dock but the DisplayPort is not detected. When I plug it in nothing happens and xrandr says:

```
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I tried different DisplayPort cables and ports in the dock. I also tried different displays. I also tried to switch back to the default GNOME display manager, but that didn't work either.

This is the dock I'm using: https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/docking/universal-cable-docks-usb/Thinkpad-USB-C-Dock/p/40A90090US

This is my computer: https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-t-series/ThinkPad-T480s/p/22TP2TT480S

**EDIT:** It suddenly started working. I restarted a few times and tried VGA instead of DisplayPort, which worked. When I switched back to DisplayPort everything worked fine.

Comment: In my case it always worked on a T480s running Ubuntu 18.10 + Lubuntu 18.04. It never worked on a One Mix 2S (7" laptop) running Ubuntu MATE 18.10. Then I realized it worked in Windows 10 when I _started_ a firmware update of the dock where I was asked to power cycle it. Afterwards, in Linux I still had no luck until I power cycled the dock again.

Comment: downvoted, you should accept the very nice, detailed answer given, or make a comment to the person stating why it did not solve your problem

Comment: @emilBeBri It solved itself for me long before the answer was given so I don't know if it is a good solution. I guess it helped you? In that case I could mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, sorry :)  I will remove the downvote once it isn't locked anymore. 
 No, It turned out to be a faulty cable on my end.

Answer (score 4):

I find this solution for with Lenovo T480s, Ubuntu 19.04 and dockstation Thinkpad 135 W.

As a root user create a **file** **`20-displaylink.conf`** under:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "DisplayLink"
  Driver "modesetting"
  Option "PageFlip" "false"
EndSection
```

Steps to do it:

To create the file:

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/

touch 20-displaylink.conf

sudo nano 20-displaylink.conf
```

paste the content

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "DisplayLink"
Driver "modesetting"
Option "PageFlip" "false"
EndSection
```

then

```
control + O
```

to save

then

```
control + x
```

to exit nano.

Then reboot to be effective.

Keep using "modesetting" driver, and disabling page flipping is necessary.

Source:
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades

Displayport ubuntu troubleshooting page
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/topics/103927-troubleshooting-ubuntu

P.S.: I am using IO adapters from DVI (monitor) to dport (dock).